# Pass Variable from Activity to AsynTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, location

I have a App with a Navigation Drawer and some fragments.

In my MainActivity i get the actual lat & long Location of the device.

On my first Fragment in the drawer i load in a AsyncTask some stuff out of my Database on my Webserver

For this request i need my Lat & Long variables from the MainActivity.

But how can i call  a getLag() Method from MainActivity out of my AsyncTask or get my 2 variables?

I need the variables in the Methode updateJSONdata which is called in doInBackround()

```
public class LoadEvents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{

        Activity activity;
        ListFragment LF;
        String TAG;

        public LoadEvents(Activity A, ListFragment lf, String TAG) {

            this.TAG = TAG;
            this.LF = lf;
            this.activity = A;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


            MySwipeRefreshLayout srl = (MySwipeRefreshLayout) LF.getView().findViewById(R.id.srl);

            if(srl!=null){
                srl.setRefreshing(true);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            updateJSONdata(TAG, activity);




            return null;

        }
```

Comment: How are you storing your lat/lon?  A `LatLng` Object?

Comment: You can pass like new `LoadEvents().execute("pass here");` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment onAttach()

```
MainActivity mainActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;             
}
```

Calling Activity method like this in your fragment

```
if (mainActivity != null)
    latLng = mainActivity.getLatLng(); //getLatLng() is a method defined in MainActivity
```

Comment: I tried this but i always geht the error 
    `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double[] paketname.getLatLng()' on a null object reference´

Comment: my fault, dont initalized a arraylist ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**1 - Call fragment function from MainActivity**

```
public class LoadEvents extends AsyncTask<Void, LatLng, Boolean>{
 //....
    @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(LatLng... arg0) {
            LatLng myLatLng = arg0[0];

            updateJSONdata(TAG, activity);
            return null;

        }
}
```

There is a method in Fragment

```
public void processAsync(LatLng latlng){
    new LoadEvents().execute(LatLng latlng);
}
```

Call your method from MainActivity

```
myfragment.processAsync(myLatLng);
```

**2 - Pass your LatLng parameter to Your Fragment**

- Pass your LatLng parameter to your fragment as Json string Bundle
- Get the LatLng object again
- Call `processAsync(myLatLng);`